# adding elements of a record type

Tags: haskell, record

So I have a record type:

```
data Box = Box { edge :: Char
                   , time1 :: [Int]
                   , time2 :: Int
                   }
             deriving Eq
```

and this list over here:

```
list_of_boxes :: [Box]
```

How can I sum the values for `time1` in each box of the list, then find which box gives the highest value for `time1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work

```
maximumBy (compare `on` sum . time1) list_of_boxes
```

You will need to import `Data.List` and `Data.Function`.

Answer (score 1):

This will sum every list *only once*:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) . map (\x -> (sum . time1 $ x , x)) $ list_of_boxes
```

The above can be shortened a bit using arrows:

```
import Control.Arrow
snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) . map (sum . time1 &&& id) $ list_of_boxes
```